# Any way to override "Constant String too Long" without concatenating strings?

Tags: java, string

I have a long program that requires a rudimentary declaration of 2 strings, str1 and str2. However, when using data, I get a "constant string too long" error in Java. Is there any way to bypass this without breaking up the strings and concatenating them?

Comment: It's a hard limit, not something you can just ignore. I would keep the long Strings as resources and load them during runtime.

Comment: Have you tried using a string builder or string buffer  ?

Comment: @StackFlowed, sorry I am a novice, but how could I implement any of those two?

Comment: Java is not a scripting language, and Java programs are not scripts. Netbeans has nothing to do with it. You have no option but to change your code so as to use shorter strings. @Kayaman Loading long Strings as resources won't change their length or cure the problem

Comment: Show some code; a too long constant string seems exotic.

Comment: @EJP It's not (only) the length that is the issue here, but the fact that he is dealing with a constant, with well defined limits.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would read the string from a resource as Kayaman suggested,
assuming your string is put in the file mystring.txt in the same directory as MyClass.java and lines are separated with `\n`. MyClass.class needs to be changed to the name of your class.

```
private static String myString = null;

public static String getMyString() throws IOException {
    if (null == myString) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("mystring.txt")))) {
            myString = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
    }
    return myString;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = getMyString();
    System.out.println("str = " + str);
}
```

Comment: This won't actually solve the problem The strings will still be too long.

Comment: @EJP It will solve the problem. There is no constant here. One can only have a string constant included in a java file up to  65535 bytes, one can have a much larger String in memory as long as it is created at run-time such as by reading it through a resource. I just tried it with a 200k resource and it worked while the same contents in a string in java source caused the compile error.